# Windows phone 7 Apps in new Windows phone 8 OS version

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I have developed a windows phone7 application and its target windows phone OS version is 7.1.

The problem is, I saw in some Blogs saying that windows phone 7 apps are not working with new windows phone 8. So I would like to know if my app works in windows phone 8 as well.

Therefore what's the best way to test if my app works in the new windows phone OS version 8.

Thanks inadvance...!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Download the Windows Phone 8 SDK and deploy your .xap to it and try.
http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

They do work in WP8, however will not have as good performance.

Comment: Can I install windows phone 8 SDK on windows 7 desktop operating System?

Comment: No you need Windows 8 due to the virtual machine requirement.

Comment: Thanks robertftw. So generally if I have targetted the windows phone OS version is 7.1 when I made the App, do you beleive it will work in windows 8 as well. Because that OS requirement and I don't have a windows 8 phone there is no way for me to test it out...

Comment: It will most certainly work but if you upgrade it to a Windows Phone 8 project the performance will be a lot better for phones with WP8, however the same .xap will not work on WP7. That's why it's best to keep two separate projects for WP7 and WP8.